# Crystal Formula to sum time field in footer

Tags: time, crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to add/sum up TIME and have it in TIME format HH:MM in the footer
The field was a number field only showing by minutes (Example: 60.00) and created a formula to convert it to HHMM (01:00) by:

```
whileprintingrecords;
numberVar hrs;
numberVar min;
stringVar hhmm;
hrs := Remainder(Truncate({field.duration}/60),60);
min := Remainder({field.duration},60);
hhmm := totext(hrs,"00") + ":" + totext(min,"00"); 
hhmm
```

Now I need to add it in the footer but in format HH:MM
any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you kind of answered your own question. Instead of doing that formula for each record's duration just do it for the sum of the durations.

```
local numbervar sum_mins := sum([field.duration}); //sum up each record's duration in mins
local numbervar hrs;
local numbervar mins;
hrs := truncate(sum_mins/60); //get whole hours
mins := remainder(sum_mins,60); //get remaining minutes
totext(hrs,'00') + ':' + totext(mins,'00')
```

Then place this formula in the report's footer.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I did try your formula but get a error for the mins := remainder(Sum_mins/60); error is "Not enough arguments have been given to this function"

Comment: figured it out Ryan.      local numbervar sum_mins := sum([field.duration}); //sum up each record's duration in mins
local numbervar hrs;
local numbervar mins;
hrs := truncate(sum_mins/60); //get whole hours
mins := remainder(sum_mins,60); //get remaining minutes
totext(hrs,'00') + ':' + totext(mins,'00')

Comment: @Dagz200 The correct syntax is `remainder(sum_mins,60)`. The slash should be a comma. See CR's reference for the remainder() function.

Answer (score 0):

Create formula in call it **"FieldToInt"** details

```
int(fieldname);
```

Then, create another formula for remaining decimal for minutes **"FieldToDec"**

```
({fieldname} - {fieldtoint}) * 100
```

Finally in group footer add this formula

```
numbervar hh;
numbervar mm;
numbervar a;
numbervar b;
numbervar c;

hh := sum({FieldToInt},{group}); // sum of hh (in hh.mm)
mm := sum({FieldTodec},{group}); // sum of mm (in hh.mm)

//formula to convert total mm to hh.mm
 a := truncate(mm / 60);
 b := a * 60;
 c := (mm - b) / 100;

//This will be the final total hrs output
hh + (a + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Two Formula

1. Create this formula (@time) to convert all the string fields to time and then to seconds:

   ```
   timevar t:= time({time_field});
   (hour(t)*3600) + (minute(t)*60) + second(t);
   ```
2. Create this formula to add all the seconds and convert them back to hh: mm: ss:

   ```
   numbervar fin_t := sum({@time},{groupName}); //@time is the formula you create in the 1st step
   NumberVar Hours   := Truncate (fin_t/3600);
   NumberVar Minutes := Truncate (Remainder (fin_t,3600)/60);
   NumberVar Seconds := Remainder (fin_t,60) ;
   ```

   Place it on the Report Footer.

   ```
   Totext (Hours, "00") + ':'+ Totext (Minutes, "00") + ':' + Totext(Seconds, "00");
   ```